# JPA Repository does not find existing entity with relation to the current entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have a code which find the current logged user and find it by username.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
MyUserDetails principal = (MyUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
current = userService.findByUsername(principal.getUsername());
```

After this I am trying to find entity with relation to the current logged user returned from `UserProfileService`

```
 userProfile = userProfileService.findByUser(current);
```

This is work fine for another entities but for `userProfile` entity is not returning the record which have `userProfile` relation between

> UserProfile Entity field mapping

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "userProfile")
private User user;
```

> User Entity field reference to userProfile

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_profile_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private UserPrifile userProfile;
```

> User Profile Repository method

```
   Optional<UserProfile> findByUser(User user);
```

This does not work its not finding the user profile with the current user relation in the databse.Is working for antoher entity but not for this any clue where would be the problem

EDIT:
I work around it for search by User ID not by User but still can't understand why is not returning the record as this work for another entity and return.

Answer (score 0):

the question isn't clear. We don't see your repository and entity classes. Which do you use entity in which repository. Please share it with us. I guess,User Entity has UserProfile entity, so maybe try;

```
Optional<User> findByUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile);
```

on the User repository. Because User should have UserProfile. You have @OneToOne UserProfile relation in the User entity